# Selenium Basic. How to deal with incorrect login info

Tags: vba, selenium

I currently have an excel macro written that displays a userform that asks for a username and password. when the info is entered a selenium chromedriver is launched, the login page is opened, and the user entered login credentials are sent to be entered. This works well if the info is correct but if the wrong info is sent obviously it won't login, so the rest of the code runs looking for data on the page that doesn't exist and I get a runtime error. I want some kind of code that recognizes the login was wrong, informs the user via message box(or other means), and exits the sub. Here's what I have.

```
'SSO is the username in this case
Dim SSO
Dim password
SSO = SSOText.Value
password = passwordText.Value

Dim cd As Selenium.ChromeDriver
Set cd = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
cd.Start
cd.Get "desiredURL"
'wait 5 seconds for page to load (may need to change time)
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:06"))

'store HTML locations as variables
Dim UsernameInput As Selenium.WebElement
Dim PasswordInput As Selenium.WebElement
Dim LogInButton As Selenium.WebElement
Set UsernameInput = cd.FindElementByName("username")
Set PasswordInput = cd.FindElementByName("password")
Set LogInButton = cd.FindElementByName("submit")

'send the user entered login credentials to HTML address
UsernameInput.SendKeys SSO
PasswordInput.SendKeys password
'click login
LogInButton.Click
'wait for login to load page
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))

'grab data
Dim lineTable As Selenium.WebElement
Set lineTable = cd.FindElementById("lineTable")
lineTable.AsTable.ToExcel ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("C2 1st Shift Production Report").Range("X2")

'clear data from userform
Unload Me
```

Also I have explicit waits written in the code to wait for pages to load. These work 95% of the time but that 5% it doesn't wait long enough. If anyone knows a way to guarantee I won't get a runtime error from a page not loading that would also be great! Thanks!

Comment: I don't use selenium but what I'll try is identify an element that will appear IF the login is incorrect then do a `While` loop looking for the said element. If it appears then do whatever you want. You can also check for another element that will appear if the login is successful in the same loop so that you can move on to the rest of the code. Make sure to add a time-based condition so that you don't loop infinitely.

Comment: I believe you will find what you need if you Take a look at these videos series https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLNIs-AWhQzcl3xKvF8sVL4sWRWICj_clM